# How to test controllers import/export csv files actions in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, rspec, controller

In one of my projects there is a controller which allows you to import & export data in csv format. As of now it works. but there are many developers on that project, and i'm afraid this functionality could be broken. Initially there were no tests. What would be most efficient way of testing this functionality?

Comment: unit spec the controller, unit spec the lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way to test this functionality, would be unit testing the classes that imports/exports the csv data, then testing the controller calls for this classes, and its response formats.